# JavaFX: concatenating sequences

Tags: javafx, sequence

Is there a standard library function or built-in construct to concatenate two sequences in JavaFX?

[Here](http://blogs.oracle.com/michaelheinrichs/entry/internal_design_of_javafx_sequences1) a Sequences.concatenate() function is mentioned, but it is nowhere to be seen in the official [API](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.2/docs/api/javafx.util/javafx.util.Sequences.html).

Of course one could iterate over each sequence, inserting the values into a new sequence e.g:

```
function concatenate(seqA: Object[], seqB: Object[]) : Object[] {
    for(b in seqB) insert b into seqA;
    seqA;
}
```

..but surely something as basic as concatenation is already defined for us somewhere..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple, since there cannot be sequence in sequence (it all gets flattened), you can do it like this:

```
var a = [1, 2];
var b = [3, 4];
// just insert one into another
insert b into a;
// a == [1, 2, 3, 4];

// or create a new seq
a = [b, a];
// a == [3, 4, 1, 2];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Inserting into a sequence creates a new sequence as well, as sequences are immutable.